# No puedo insertar dato foreign key, ayuda!

Tags: php, html, bootstrap

necesito de su ayuda, tengo un formulario PHP, el cual en un HTML select obtengo datos de una tabla, los datos que obtengo son PK de otra tabla (FK), para luego ingresarlos a la base de datos, el problema es que cuando doy al botón ingresar, éstos datos no se ingresan a la BD y ni siquiera me arroja error, no sé que estoy haciendo mal, o quizás no se puede agregar un dato que ya está agregado en la bd?, les dejo el código PHP y HTML, favor sus comentarios:

```
 <?php
include "../conexionBD.php";

if ($op == "add"){

    //asigna el post a las variables
    $Numero     = $_POST['Numero'];
    $Sector     = $_POST['ListaSector'];
    $Capacidad  = $_POST['Capacidad'];
    $Listagarzon            = $_POST['Listagarzon'];


    //prepara la query
    $stmt = $bd->prepare("
    INSERT INTO mesa (Numero, Sector, Capacidad, Rut_garzon) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

    //asigna las variables a la query
    $stmt->bind_param('isis', $Numero, $Sector, $Capacidad, $Listagarzon);

    //ejecuta la query
    $stmt->execute();       
}

header('Location: modmesas.php');
?>


<section>
    <div class="container">
     <h4 align="center">Ingresar mesa</h4>
    <form action="controladorMesas.php?op=add" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Numero">Número:</label>
        <input type="number" step="1" class="form-control" id="Numero" name="Numero" min="1" max="20" placeholder="Ingresar número de mesa">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Sector">Sector:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="sel2" name="ListaSector">
            <option value="Primer piso">Primer piso</option>
            <option value="Segundo piso">Segundo piso</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Capacidad">Capacidad:</label>
        <input type="number" step="1" class="form-control" id="Capacidad" name="Capacidad" min="2" max="6" placeholder="Ingresar capacidad de personas">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Garzon">Garzon:</label>         
               <?php echo '<select class="form-control" id="sel3" name="Listagarzon">
        <option>Seleccione:</option>'?>

        <?php
        include "../conexionBD.php"; // este esta de más, ya estas llamando la conexion arriba

$query = 'SELECT * FROM garzon';

$result = $bd->query($query);
         while ( $row = $result->fetch_array() )    
   {
        ?>
        <option value=" <?php echo $row['Rut']  //el echo no esta cerrado ?> " >
         <?php echo $row['Rut']; ?>
    </option>
     <?php
  }    
  ?>   
        </select>
        <?php
  // para que esta este PHP?
 ?>         
    </div>

    <div class="btn-lg">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="agregar()">Agregar</button>
    </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: agrega mas información sobre todo de la funcion agrega() , no se ve en ninguna parte. es javascript?

Comment: Hola, correcto la función agregar() es javascript, pero es una ventana de confirmación solamente, nada fuera de lo normal, saludos!

Comment: bueno, entonces podrías agregarlo solo para determinar mejor una solución, ya que desconozco si realizas una petición ajax en tu ventana de confirmación...

Comment: No uso ajax, solo javascript básico.

Comment: entonces como realizas el posteo desde esa ventana de confirmación, javascript al servidor?

Answer (score 0):

Tendria que quedar asi:

```
<?php
try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'root', '');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
}


if(isset($_POST['add'])){
if(!empty($_POST['Numero']) && !empty($_POST['ListaSector']) && !empty($_POST['Capacidad']) && !empty($_POST['Listagarzon'])){
    $add = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO mesa (Numero, Sector, Capacidad, Rut_garzoncha) VALUES (:Numero, :Sector, :Capacidad, :Rut_garzon)");
    $add->bindValue('Numero, Sector, Capacidad, Rut_garzon', ($_POST['nombre']));
    $add->bindValue(':Sector', ($_POST['Numero']));
    $add->bindValue(':Capacidad', ($_POST['Capacidad']));
    $add->bindValue(':Rut_garzoncha', ($_POST['Listagarzon']));
    $add->execute();
    echo "El nuevo cliente fue agregado <a href='../'>volver</a>";
}
else{
    echo "Ingresar datos <a href='../'>volver</a>";
}
}
?>


<section>
<div class="container">
<h4 align="center">Ingresar mesa</h4>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="Numero">Número:</label>
<input type="number" step="1" class="form-control" id="Numero" name="Numero" min="1" max="20" placeholder="Ingresar número de mesa">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="Sector">Sector:</label>
<select class="form-control" id="sel2" name="ListaSector">
<option value="Primer piso">Primer piso</option>
<option value="Segundo piso">Segundo piso</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="Capacidad">Capacidad:</label>
<input type="number" step="1" class="form-control" id="Capacidad" name="Capacidad" min="2" max="6" placeholder="Ingresar capacidad de personas">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="Garzon">Garzon:</label>         
<select class="form-control" id="sel3" name="Listagarzon">
<option>Seleccione:</option>
<?php
$consulta = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM garzon");
while ($row = $consulta->fetch()){
?>
<option value=" <?=$row['Rut'];?>"><?=$row['Rut'];?></option>
<?php
}    
?>   
</select>       
</div>

<div class="btn-lg">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="agregar()" name="add">Agregar</button>
</div>
</form>
```

pd: no puedo comentar, no llego a los 50 puntos.

Comment: Hola, el add está en  <form action="controladorMesas.php?op=add"

Comment: y probaste quitar el add de `<form action="controladorMesas.php?op=add"`?

Comment: Si lo quité pero sigue pasando lo mismo, le doy a agregar y la página carga, pero no inserta nada, lo reviso en la bd y no hay nada, lo que me parece más raro aún es que en la bd inserté los datos y se agregaron correctamente, caso contrario en la aplicación ya que no me los agrega :/

Comment: Ahi hice unos comentario en el codigo que publicaste.

Comment: otra pregunta: el select ultimo, te trae el listado que pedis desde la base de datos?

Comment: Ahi hice unos cambios, pero tendrias que probarlo con los datos que necesitas agregar.

Comment: OK, muchas, gracias, voy a probar, y sí el último select me muestra unos datos de otra tabla que son PK en esa, por lo tanto en esta tabla donde los quiero agregar son FK.

Comment: Ah, ok... bueno probalo y cualquier cosa, lo modificamos y vamos probando

Comment: Aún con el mismo problema, deshabilite el select y el formulario me guarda correctamente los otros datos, con eso corroboro que el select es el problema, quizás está mal programado :/

Comment: ok... ahi lo miro

Comment: Ahi lo actualice `<select class="form-control" id="sel3" name="Listagarzon">
    <option>Seleccione:</option>
        <?php
        // actualice el pedido para el select option
        $consulta = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM garzon");
        while ($row = $consulta->fetch()){
        ?>
        <option value="<?=$row['Rut'];?>"><?=$row['Rut'];?></option>
        <?php
        }    
        ?>   
    </select>`

Comment: cuidado con las mayusculas y chequea bien que todo coincida, ahi lo deje mas prolijo

Comment: Compañero, utilicé el código que me enviaste, le modifiqué algunas cosas, luego fui a la BD y le modifique al campo Rut_garzon de la tabla mesa y le puse Nulo Si y Predeterminado Null, luego probé nuevamente a insertar los datos y milagrosamente se insertaron correctamente!, muchas gracias por tu tiempo y ayuda, muy agradecido! :)

Comment: Así quedó el código:  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="Garzon">Garzon:</label> 
  <select class="form-control" id="sel3" name="Listagarzon">
  <option>Seleccione:</option>
  <?php // actualice el pedido para el select option 
  $result = $bd->query("SELECT * FROM garzon"); 
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['Rut'];?>"><?php echo $row['Rut'];?></option> 
  <?php } ?>
  </select>
  </div>

Comment: Bueno genial, me alegro que funcione. No tienes porque agradecerme... te dejo un abrazo grande!

Comment: @Pedro si está respuesta te ayudó, considera votarla positivamente